# Connecting two NG-Repeats

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have two ng-repeats that i would like to connect together using their unique id. The idea is that you click a movie poster and the corresponding streaming video will come up the screen above using CSS hide/show. This is what i have so far:

```
<div class="contentContainer" ng-app="webtest">

      <div class="" ng-controller="LandingPageController">    

          <div class="videoContainer" ng-repeat="movie in movies" > 
             <video width="800" controls>
                 <source src="{{movie.stream}}" type="video/mp4">
             </video>                         
          </div>  

     <div class="moviesContainer">                                   
          <div class="movieCell" ng-repeat="movie in movies">                   
                <a href="#tab{{movie.id}}">
                   <img class="movieCellImage" src="content/images/moviePosters/{{movie.images.cover}}">
                   <div class="movieCellImageBackground">
                   <div class="movieCellTitle">{{movie.title}} {{movie.id}}</div>
                   </div>
                </a>                           
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using JavaScript / jQuery event handlers / DOM manipulation? Why aren't you using `ng-click` / `ng-show`?

Comment: What is your problem? Everything works?

Comment: You do not have element with id `#tab`. Consider using [`ngClick`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Angular, you don't have to/ should use jQuery.
Angular allows you to handle `click` event with `ng-click`.

1. To your `<a>` add `ng-click="select_video(movie.id)"` (you can also remove `href`).
2. And you controller should look like this:

   ```
   var app = angular.module('{your-app-id}', []);

   app.controller('LandingPageController', function ($scope) {
       $scope.selected_id = null;
       $scope.movies = (...) /* The array of movies. */
       $scope.select_video = function(id) {
           $scope.selected_id = id;
       };
   });
   ```
3. Then, to every `.videoContainer > *` add `ng-if="selected_id == movie.id"`.

Should work, let me know if it doesn't.

EDIT:
Also reorganize your HTML like this:

```
<div ng-controller="...">
    <div class="videoContainer" ng-repeat="...">
        <div ng-if="...">
            <!-- <video /> here, and stuff visible only if this video is selected -->
        </div>

        <!-- Your <a /> -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need 2 loops. Create a reference to selected item, and set it up in the loop like:

`<a ng-click="selectedMovie = movie">...</a>`

Let then angular do everything for you.

```
<div ng-controller="LandingPageController"> 

    <video width="800" controls>
        <source src="{{selectedMovie.streams[0].url}}" type="video/mp4">
    </video>  
    <div class="newscontainer">{{selectedMovie.id}} CLICKED</div>      

    <div class="moviesContainer" id="tabs">                  
        <div class="movieCell" ng-repeat="movie in movies">                   
            <a ng-click="selectedMovie = movie">
                <img class="movieCellImage" src="content/images/moviePosters/{{movie.images.cover}}">
                <div class="movieCellImageBackground">
                    <div class="movieCellTitle">{{movie.title}} {{movie.id}}</div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

Not tested, may not work. If so, try `<a ng-click="$parent.selectedMovie = movie">...</a>`